# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function Android Browser

Tags: android-browser

I am getting a strange error on Android Browser that it constantly says

```
    Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

On a function that is working perfectly on all other browsers even Safari. The website loads everything perfectly on all the browsers, on computer as well as mobiles but when it is viewed on Android browser it throws off that error. I have checked it over all and jquery is included only once. I can post the code here but I dont think it would be of much help because at the start it was giving above mentioned error on a function which i tried to resolve. After that it started giving the same error on another function and it is carrying on like this.

Here is a reference

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: XXXXXXXXXXX,
            data: dataObj,
            cache: false,
            success: function (resp) {
                if (resp.startsWith("Error:")) {
                    console.log(resp)
                }
                else
                {
                    clusters.clearLayers();
                    // common.clearLayers();
                    var result = JSON.parse(resp)
                    console.log(result.user);
                    if (result.user == 'free')
                    {
                        makeFreePokemon(result[0]['hits']['hits'])
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        makePokemon(result[0]['hits']['hits'])
                    }
                    // if (result[0]['hits']['total'] > 1000) {
                    //   window.setTimeout(search(),500)
                    // }
                }
            }
        })
```

In the above code it gives the undefined error ON

```
if (resp.startsWith("Error:")) {
```

When I solve this, it starts giving the same error another location.

Anyhelp would be really great.
Thanks

Comment: Hi. can you provide some code thanks, bit hard to diagnose without it

Comment: Added a code snippet

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Could you please post a solution if you've found one?

Comment: Yes I found the solution to this. It was related to the version i was using and the function was not there. Also it used to use a different datatype as compared to what i was trying to access it with i think.